# Error when starting an react-native app in IOS 11

Tags: ios, react-native

When starting an react-native app in IOS 11, it starts very slow and in console from Xcode I see the following:

```
2019-08-12 20:48:18.605137+0200 soiduplaanPimedatele[2593:839895] Task <3B1F8B0C-40DD-47BF-92C0-C5414ACF5B49>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
2019-08-12 20:48:18.627675+0200 soiduplaanPimedatele[2593:839901] Task <3B1F8B0C-40DD-47BF-92C0-C5414ACF5B49>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-08-12 20:48:18.627 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:236] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x108900000> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x281151730>, executor: (null))
2019-08-12 20:48:18.633132+0200 soiduplaanPimedatele[2593:839816] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x108900000> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x281151730>, executor: (null))
2019-08-12 20:48:18.685 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:293] Running application soiduplaanPimedatele ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
```

Has someone encountered something similar?
Otherwise the App runs as normal.

Comment: It seems that during launch it tries to make an http call and that is timing out?

Comment: @onnoweb yes, as far as I understand, when developing an react-native app, react-native uses metro js bundler which creates an express server which serves the js bundle. When you use the ios simulator the "native app" downloads and runs it.

I am not sure what happens when I run the App on a device...